# How to implement authentication in WebService

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, authentication, iis-6

I going to create one web service in c#.Client will send username and password.I want to authenticate the user before reaching to a web method,ie in IIS level.Is it possible create a filter in c#.Can anyone pls share the code or link.User Details are stored in MSSQL database[i want to validate such a user is existing in Database.If user is not existing,then i want to block the request,there itself. Purpose is to avoid validation of user in every web method].

Comment: "Can anyone pls share the code or link": how about you write some and then come back with a real question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend building a REST based webservice and sending through an API key rather than usernames and passwords.

Have a look at: [REST GET requests, verbs and apikey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334997/rest-get-requests-verbs-and-apikey)

Then just Google REST based ASP.NET Webservices for heaps of tutorials on how to accomplish it.

**Updated to show implementation**

Note: I can't find the original page but this code was based off a sample somewhere.

**Step 1 - Edit web.config**

Insert this in the  system.serviceModel  section.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <clear />
    <behavior>
      <!-- This behavior enables API Key Verification -->
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="API.APIKeyAuthorization, API" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Step 2 - Create API Authorization Class**

Change the code in IsValidAPI key to suit your actual situation. You can see mine goes to a function to test if the API key is valid.

```
namespace API
{
public class APIKeyAuthorization : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    public const string APIKEY = "APIKey";
    public const string APIKEYLIST = "APIKeyList";

    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        return IsValidAPIKey(operationContext);
    }

    public bool IsValidAPIKey(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        // if verification is disabled, return true
        if (Global.APIKeyVerification == false)
            return true;

        string key = GetAPIKey(operationContext);

        // Convert the string into a Guid and validate it
        if (BusinessLogic.User.ApiKey.Exists(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Send back an HTML reply
            CreateErrorReply(operationContext, key);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string GetAPIKey(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        // Get the request message
        var request = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage;

        // Get the HTTP Request
        var requestProp = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];

        // Get the query string
        NameValueCollection queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(requestProp.QueryString);

        // Return the API key (if present, null if not)
        return queryParams[APIKEY];
    }

    private static void CreateErrorReply(OperationContext operationContext, string key)
    {
        // The error message is padded so that IE shows the response by default
        using (var sr = new StringReader("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + APIErrorHTML))
        {
            XElement response = XElement.Load(sr);
            using (Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null, response))
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty responseProp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, StatusDescription = String.Format("'{0}' is an invalid API key", key) };
                responseProp.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "text/html";
                reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = responseProp;
                operationContext.RequestContext.Reply(reply);
                // set the request context to null to terminate processing of this request
                operationContext.RequestContext = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public const string APIErrorHTML = @"
<html>
<head>
    <title>Request Error - No API Key</title>
    <style type=""text/css"">
        body
        {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: x-large;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Request Error
    </h1>
    <p>
        A valid API key needs to be included using the apikey query string parameter
    </p>
</body>
</html>
";
    }
}
```

API authorization is done before you even hit the web method. However this example shows the API key being passed as a querystring. Follow more examples in the link above to change this to sending it through HTTP headers. A cleaner approach, it doesn't then mess up your URL's. But that all depends on your requirements.

**Update**
Actually I just came across this: Microsoft ASP.NET Web API - http://www.asp.net/web-api

Try that :)

Comment: My doubt is how to handle the request befor it reach to webmethod.